# How to search and modify floating values that follow a string in a file using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, full-text-search

Lets say we have "abc {{1.1 2.2}}" occurring multiple times in a file and I want to modify it to "xyz {{2.2 4.4}}" which is basically:

- Change abc to xyz.
- And multiply the floating values by 2 that appear in the curly braces (always preceded by abc keyword).

```
abc {{1.1 2.2}} ----------> xyz {{2.2 4.4}}
```

This modification must be done to all instances of the file.
Here's the code that I tried but was able to replace only abc to xyz and couldn't figure out how to do the operations by extracting those floating values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open(FILE, "</tmp/yourfile.txt") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

foreach(@lines) {
   $_ =~ s/abc/xyz/g;
}

open(FILE, ">/tmp/yourfile.txt") || die "File not found";
print FILE @lines;
close(FILE);
```

Any sort of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input file? Without content of input file it will be a guess game.

Comment: Is double curly brackets intentional? Without additional description/explanation this form of representing data seems not optimal.

Comment: `{{ x.x x.x}}` is just used a representation of values. It's just a form of representation done in the .txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you'd want to keep the number of decimals (and/or control it), and that the floats may need be manipulated in ways more complex than mere `*2`

```
perl -wE' $_=q(abc {{0.2 14.55}}); 
    say; 
    s{ abc \s+ \{\s*\{\s* \K  
       ([0-9]+\.([0-9]+)) (\s+) ([0-9]+\.([0-9]+))  (?=\s*\}\s*\})
    }{
       ($l2,$l5) = map length, $2, $5; 
       sprintf("%.${l2}f", 2*$1) .$3. sprintf("%.${l5}f", 2*$4)
    }ex; 
    say'
```

This makes some basic assumptions.  It prints

```
abc {{0.2 14.55}}
abc {{0.4 29.10}}
```

Comments

- The `\K` makes it drop all matches up to that point; they need not be captured and re-entered as replacement as they haven't been "consumed."  So we match that first part and leave it alone
- The `}e` modifier makes it evaluate the replacement side as Perl code. There we format numbers resulting from multiplication with the number of decimal places of the originals
- The bit in the end of the matching part, `(?=...)`, is a [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)
- If numbers may come with `-/+` then these characters need be added to the pattern

  ```
  ([-+]?[0-9]+\.([0-9]+))
  ```

  If that `+` need be reproduced in output as well then you also need to capture the sign `([-+]?)`, so to be able to check in the replacement side and add it (if it was there).

Answer (score 1):

No sample of input file was provide by OP and due this reason the following code may not reflect proper solution.

It was assumed that the pattern `abc {{x.x x.x}}` will not present more than once on the line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $debug = 0;

for (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say $_ if $debug;
    if( /(.*)?abc\s*\{\{\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\d\.]+)\s*\}\}(.*)/ ) {
        my($a,$b) = ($2,$3);
        $a *= 2;
        $b *= 2;
        say $1 . "xyz {{$a $b}}" . $4;
    } else {
        say $_;
    }
}

__DATA__
This an example data abc {{1.1 2.2}} which required some manipulation.

We should take abc {{1.1 2.2}} and replace 'abc' to 'xyz' take two
float numbers in curly brackets and multiply each by 2, write result
as xyz {{2.2 4.4}}.

Let's play with some numbers
        abc {{7.2 12.4}}
            boy {{0.5 8.2}}
        put {{2.3 8.6}}
            got {{4.1 2.3}}
        abc {{0.5 4.9}}

Note: numbers can have values different from provided sample
```

Output

```
This an example data xyz {{2.2 4.4}} which required some manipulation.

We should take xyz {{2.2 4.4}} and replace 'abc' to 'xyz' take two
float numbers in curly brackets and multiply each by 2, write result
as xyz {{2.2 4.4}}.

Let's play with some numbers
                xyz {{14.4 24.8}}
                        boy {{0.5 8.2}}
                put {{2.3 8.6}}
                        got {{4.1 2.3}}
                xyz {{1 9.8}}

Note: numbers can have values different from provided sample
```

Comment: Your assumption of `abc {{x.x x.x}}` won't be appearing more than once in a line is correct.

Answer (score 0):

My Perl regex is rusty but something like this should help:

```perl
use Test::More tests => 6;

sub match_and_replace
{
    $_[0] =~ /abc \{\{([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+) ([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)}}/;
    my $my1 = $1*2;
    my $my3 = $3*2;
    my $ret = $_[0];
    $ret =~ s/abc \{\{$1 $3}}/xyz \{\{$my1 $my3}}/g;
    return $ret;
}

is(match_and_replace('abc {{1.1 2.2}}'), 'xyz {{2.2 4.4}}', 'simple float');
is(match_and_replace('abc {{12.12 23.23}}'), 'xyz {{24.24 46.46}}', 'bigger float');
is(match_and_replace('abc {{1.99 99.1}}'), 'xyz {{3.98 198.2}}', 'another float');
is(match_and_replace('abc {{.5 .5}}'), 'xyz {{1 1}}', 'only fractional part');
is(match_and_replace('abc {{2 6}}'), 'xyz {{4 12}}', 'only integer part');
is(match_and_replace('abc'), 'abc', 'no match');
```

Comment: That will fail for `abc {{1.1 2.2}} abc {{1.1 3.3}}`.

Comment: That will fail for `abc`. (It will issue warnings.)

Comment: I suppose it would fail for values whose `decimal part >=0.5`.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question @Jaks ! I've updated the answer to reflect.

Comment: Well, you fixed one of the three issues I raised.